# Java BigDecimal - rounding down to the user-provided multiple

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a business requirement where the input values should be rounded down to the multiples provided by user. Here is the example:

```
Case | input | multiples | output
1    | 43.0  | 0.1       | 43.0
2    | 43.1  | 0.1       | 43.1
3    | 43.2  | 0.1       | 43.2
4    | 43.0  | 0.2       | 43.0
5    | 43.1  | 0.2       | 43.0
6    | 43.2  | 0.2       | 43.2
```

If the `multiples` is 0.1, then the output should be in the increments of 0.1, e.g., 43.1, 43.2, etc.

If the `multiples` is 0.2, then the output should be in the increments of 0.2, e.g., 43.0, 43.2, 43.4, etc.

What is the best way to do this in Java using `BigDecimal`? Using `BigDecimal.setScale(1, ROUND_DOWN)` I was able to restrict the number of decimal points though.

Comment: Could you please explain the rule a bit more precise. Because `input values should be rounded off` + `in case of #5 ... increment values as 0.2` + `the input is rounded down to 43.0`. First you say it should be rounded off and then you provide an example where it is rounded down.

Comment: The rounding rule for `0.1` is meaningless, as output would be always equal to the input. Does it for  `0.2` mean round down to the nearest multiple of `0.2`? So for input `43.3` the output should be `43.2`? What multiples are possible `0.3, 0.4, 3.5`? How to handle input `43.21`?

Comment: Multiples are always 0.1 or 0.2. Yes, for input 43.3 and 0.2, output should be 43.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified solution could be (pseudo code)

```
if (multiple == 0.1) then {
    output = input
} else {
    if ((int) input * 10 % 2 == 1) {
        output -= 0.1
    } else {
        output = input
    }
}
```

You need to take care about the rounding after you substract 0.1.

**edit: possible solution**

```
double input = 43.0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    double output = input;
    if ((int) (input * 10) % 2 == 1) {
        output = ((double) (int) (input * 10) - 1) / 10;
    }
    System.out.printf("input:  %f   output: %f%n", input, output);
    input += 0.1;
}
```

**resulting output**

```
input:  43.000000   output: 43.000000
input:  43.100000   output: 43.000000
input:  43.200000   output: 43.200000
input:  43.300000   output: 43.200000
input:  43.400000   output: 43.400000
input:  43.500000   output: 43.400000
input:  43.600000   output: 43.600000
input:  43.700000   output: 43.600000
input:  43.800000   output: 43.800000
input:  43.900000   output: 43.800000
input:  44.000000   output: 44.000000
```

Comment: Yes, that's the logic I have, but I was wondering if there was any better way of doing this using BigDecimal methods.

Comment: @MFIhsan I add a working example. Have a look if this might be a solution for your requirement.